# Triangle greater than (probability)

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

This one is a follow up of my previous question. But a different problem. And this one should have a more interesting answer. I don't really know how to approach this problem nonetheless reach a solution, so again help is appreciated.

**Question:**

You have a circle with radius $R$. If three points are *randomly* chosen inside this circle.
What is the probability that the three points form a triangle with an area greater than $\displaystyle \frac{R^2}{5}$?

**Edit:** Is anyone trying or maybe found an approach that might work? Is there any similar problems you've seen before that could work as a guide towards solving this one? What do you consider being the difficulties? I literally don't have any idea on where to even start.

Comment: I think, for comparing two things, both should have the same dimensions. How can you compare an area with a length? Or perhaps, you only want to compare their magnitudes...

Comment: @ABCD I agree that the question would have a more meaningful answer if we were comparing two areas.

Comment: I've edited the question!

Comment: Since it scales, can we assume that we have a unit circle, and we want the probability that the area of the triangle exceeds $1/5$?

Comment: Sure, let's assume that

Comment: [Heron Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

Comment: @Felix Marin Could you make this more precise, maybe even up to a numerical result? If so, I'd be genuinely impressed..

Comment: There is a _slightly_ similar problem to this one, that is: given $3$ randomly placed points on a circle, find the probability that they form a triangle which contains the center of the circle. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkmNXy7er84), from 1:50 onwards. Might be a good starting point.

Comment: We're talking about uniformly picked points, right? The mean of the area is calculated here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskTrianglePicking.html It says the distribution of the area isn't known. Don't know if the calculation (of the CDF) for that particular value $\frac{1}{5}$ is any easier.

Comment: @AlexandruDinu If the points are picked **on** the circle, the distribution of the area was found in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/306210 . It involves some special functions, though.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but just a simulation. I get the approximate value

$$P(A\geq \frac{1}{5}) \approx 0.45$$

Here is my Sage-code if someone wants to check it. It agrees with [the mean value of mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskTrianglePicking.html)

```
def randPt():
    r = random()**0.5 #sqrt to make it uniform
    a = random()*2*float(pi)
    return (r*cos(a), r*sin(a))

def simuTriArea():
    a,b,c = [randPt() for _ in range(3)]
    return 0.5*abs(a[0]*b[1] + b[0]*c[1] + c[0]*a[1] - b[0]*a[1] - c[0]*b[1] - a[0]*c[1])

#points([randPt() for _ in range(1000)]).show(aspect_ratio=1)
simuN = 100000
triAreas = [simuTriArea() for _ in range(simuN)]
print ("simulated P(A>0.2): %f" % (sum(1 for a in triAreas if a>0.2) / float(simuN),) )
print ("mean A: %f" %mean(triAreas))
graph = Graphics()
graph += histogram(triAreas, density=True, bins=50)
maxArea = float(3*3**0.5 / 4)
#graph += plot(???, xmin=0, xmax=maxArea)
graph.show()
```